# Develop an asynchronous generator in keras

Tags: multithreading, keras, generator

I am currently developing a CNN model in Keras using `model.fit_generator`  and I currently have a generator developed using `keras.utils.Sequences` class. My problem is that looking over GPU utilization, it is not as high as it should be meaning the current model is CPU bottle-necked. I have played around with what the generator is doing to the data to make it more efficient, but it is still bottle-necked. My ideal situation is to have the generator continuously process the data and store it into memory (even single threaded) and for it to be put into the GPU when necessary. Essentially, I was wondering if there is a way to have the generator asynchronously process the data for an efficient generator method. Currently, the generator processes a batch, loads the batch into the GPU and waits for the GPU to finish. I have tweaked `max_queue_size`, `workers`, and `use_multiprocessing`, but nothing seems to have the GPU working to its full potential.

Comment: Things are more complicated than just CPU bottleneck, did you try increasing the batch size?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes, but I do not have much leeway from just simple GPU memory constraints.

Comment: Sometimes the model is not big enough to utilize the entire GPU, but l can also refer you to using a library called TensorPack.

Answer (score 0):

GPU usage may be either data transfer or computing. Try to find out which takes longer. Then you can better understand the batch size effects.